# API key in python

Tags: python, api

Good day!

I'm trying to run this program:

```
import pandas as pd
import gmaps #import the gmaps library
import gmaps.datasets #imports the gmaps.datasets library

gmaps.configure(api_key='< API Key >') # Fill in with your API key

earthquake_df = gmaps.datasets.load_dataset_as_df('earthquakes') #equate your raw data to the designated dataset
earthquake_df.head()

locations = earthquake_df[['latitude', 'longitude']] #locate the 
weights = earthquake_df['magnitude']
fig = gmaps.figure()
fig.add_layer(gmaps.heatmap_layer(locations, weights=weights))
fig
```

But no displaying image, instead this error occurs:

```
Something went wrong authenticating with Google Maps. This may be because you did not pass in an API key, or the key you passed in was incorrect. Check the browser console, look for errors that start with Google Maps API error and compare the message against the Google Maps documentation.
```

I don't know what's that means? Please, anyone, help me! Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you supposed to keep your API key private?

Comment: I have removed your API key from your post. Since you made it publicly visible for a couple of minutes I urgently recommend you invalidate the key in your Google Cloud Console.

Comment: It will stay visible in the post edit history... you better generate a new one.